# CakePHP: Loading external controller methods in one controller

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.7

- I have a MVC setup for a "Components" section, works great.
- I have a MVC setup for a "Kits" section, works great.

However, now I want to build a **View for a "Products" section** which will merely show a few '*components*' and a few '*kits*'.

I thought the best way to do this was to import the two Index() functions from the KitsController and the ComponentsController into my Index() function in the ProductsController that would allow my Products view to access the two arrays containing the required data.

The Index() functions in the Kits and Components controllers only have:

```
  public function index() {
        $this->set('kits', $this->Kit->find('all'));
    }
```

I've tried this and similar code, but it doesn't work. I end up with a SQL error  or either a Kit, Class or Model was not found error:

```
<?php
  //Import controller
  App::import('Controller', 'Kits');
  App::import('Controller', 'Components');

  class ProductsController extends AppController {
    //Instantiation
    $Kits = new KitsController;
    $Comps = new ComponentsController;

    //Load model, components...
    $Kits  -> constructClasses();
    $Comps -> constructClasses();

    function index() {
        $Kits->index();
        $Comps->index();
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiating other Controller classes in a Controller class is a bad habit.

If I understand your intentions correctly you want to have both the Kits data and Components data available in your ProductsController. To do this you have to have to link the underlying models in some way (either [statically](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types) or [on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly)).

After doing this the ProductModel is linked with the other models so that you can get your data in the following way:

```
function index() {
    $kits = $this->Product->Kit->find('all');
    $comps = $this->Product->Component->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('kits', 'comps'));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply Semmel! I'm just trying to work out how to create the link in the underlying models. At this stage, there's no Products table, so I'm not sure how I can create the link between the models..

Comment: Okay, I got it working and got the two arrays in my ProductsController however is there any way to clean up the arrays? At the moment, the array has 3 levels:

To get the first KitID in the array, I have to go to: `$Kits[0]['Kit']['KitID']`. This means the 2nd dimension ['Kit'] is always repeated... can I remove the 2nd dimension completely by any chance? To make it: `$Kits[0]['KitID']`

Comment: This is the standard format of the retrieved data. I am not sure if a clean way to remove the 2nd dimension exists. But to get your data with `$Kits[0]['KitID']` you could manipulate your array manually (e.g. with a `foreach` loop). If you only need the IDs of your data you could also use the `'list'` find type. For full information on how to retrieve your data and the format you get read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).